# Microsoft Edge doesn't Print

Tags: printing, microsoft-edge

Both computers in the office don't print and even don't show the print dialog.  I tried Ctrl+P, Print option in the menu.  I am running Windows 10.

I attempted this [solution](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-repair-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10/) and I also tried to reset Edge, which worked for 2 minutes and stopped working again.

Comment: Can you print from other applications like MS Word?

Comment: Yes, and all the other browsers works, and apps. but the print dialog don't show up in Edge, I was testing a website (I'm developer) and need to test the printing in Edge :( I'm trying now sfc /scannow to see if this solve something.

Comment: sfc scannow no success :(

Comment: Are all Windows Updates installed?

Comment: Yes, and my work colleague has the same computer with the same issue. But I tried with another pc here and worked,  I suspect something we installed 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/ms-edge-not-printing/1c02e3d9-40ba-4663-b415-f243f3b4e605?auth=1

Comment: What program do you suspect?

Comment: No idea, we installed visual studio, sql and other tools, I uninstalled a lot of HP programs and clients.. but no success yet !

Comment: fixed :) Reset and Repair !